# Google Analytics 4 | Individual user activities tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-filters

Does Google-Analytics-4 provide the following things:

1. pages accessed
2. page accessed by whom
3. time spent on page
4. frequency of access

I am trying to see the individual user activity especially the pages he accessed in the audience and user explorer (Analysis hub)

How can I send my system user_id using angular 8 to Google analytics 4 to identify individual users and then track activities of individual users especially the pages he accessed and other.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that a) Google provides documentation on implementation and b) that [personal identifiable information](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) should not be passed on to Google Analytics.
To answer your questions though:

> 1. pages accessed

Yes, in the "Engagement" -> "Pages and screens" report for example

> page accessed by whom

You can create and use "comparisons" just like segments in "Universal Analytics". These also allow to compare Demographic groups

> time spent on page

Yes, same report "Engagement" -> "Pages and screens"

> frequency of access

If you mean the "views per user", then yes. Same report.

> How can I send my system user_id using angular 8 to Google analytics 4 to identify individual users and then track activities of individual users especially the pages he accessed and other.

Read the [general information in the documentation here (reading time 2 minutes)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9213390?hl=en&ref_topic=9303474)
Read the [technical documentation how to send the e.g. user id to analytics 4 here (reading time: 1 minute)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/user-id?platform=apps)

Hope this helps you or anyone who did not find the links